# AngularJS - Custom Directive - CSS separate file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making a custom directive `<top-nav>`.

Should I isolate the CSS for this in its own file?

What if it requires CSS from the main application that's shared across other pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at LESS and SASS css compilers.

I structure my apps like this.

```
/app
   /directives
       /fooWidget
           fooWidget.scss
           fooWidget.js
           fooWidget.html
   /directives.scss
/app.scss
/app.js
```

Comment: Thanks! Off the bat, any preference of LESS vs SASS? Or is this a Ruby vs Python style question :p

Comment: @Ricky - I would go with SASS, as it is just more powerful and you can easily add compass. More reasons: http://www.zingdesign.com/less-vs-sass-its-time-to-switch-to-sass/

Comment: @Ricky which X or Y is something you have to decide on your own. I've used compass and it does save you time, but it has it's own compiler.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to publish it somewhere then you definitely want to isolate the CSS.

If this is only for internal use, it's a matter of preference, but I think the majority of developers would prefer if it's separate.

CSS in a separate file can still inherit from CSS defined elsewhere. Eventually you'll probably end up using Gulp to minify and combine all your CSS anyway.

Comment: Thanks @MikeFeltman. Same question as Diego, would you then include your CSS in your template HTML file via a <link> tag? or just include in the parent HTML file?

Comment: Personally I like to have all of my CSS & JS loaded in my index.html file. I'm too old to keep track of where I load things from otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that as a necessity. If you are adding a template in your directive, then keeping the css to the external file won't do any harm, as the directive gets loaded when the DOM is being parsed & the style written for the element will be loaded accordingly from the external style sheet.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to use an isolate CSS file to the directive. You can use a structure for the directive like this:

```
   /clockWidget
       clockWidget.css
       clockWidget.js
       clockWidget.html
```

For the directive css it self you can create a css class that wraps all the html and use that class to affect only the directive html.

for instance, create the footer-widget css class and specify that class for the html elements of the directive.

In the clockWidget.css:

```
span .footer-widget{
  background-color: red;
}
```

then in your html:

```
    <div class="footer-widget">
      <span>I'm The footer</span>
    </div>
```

This way the css class will wrap all the html, only affecting the directive html. And you can use main application css without problems.

Comment: So if I separate the CSS, does that mean I'll need to include the CSS into my directive via a <link> tag?